# Prove that there is exactly one $w \in B(0,1)$ such that $f(w) = w$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on a domain which contains
>   the closed unit disk $\overline{B(0,1)}$. Suppose that $f$ maps
>   $\overline{B(0,1)}$ into the open unit disk $B(0,1)$, that is $|f(z)|
>  < 1$ on $\overline{B(0,1)}$. Prove that there is exactly one $w \in
>  B(0,1)$ such that $f(w) = w$.

The question can be understood as such, for the equation $f(z) = z$, there will be only one root that satisfies it, meaning the equation $f(z) - z$ has only one zero in the $B(0,1)$.

Consider the function $g(z) = f(z) - z$ and $h(z) = -z$. Now both are analytic functions in $B(0,1)$, and on the boundary $|z| = 1$, $$|g(z) - h(z)| = |f(z) < 1 = |h(z)|$$

By Rouche's Theorem, the number of zeros of $g$ and $h$ in $B(0,1)$ is the same. Since $h$ has $1$ zero , then $g$ has one zero. This means $f(z) - z = 0$ has one root, which implies there will only be one $w \in B(0,1)$ that satisfies $f(w) = w$.

Is my logic and steps correct?